# Is there a simpler to sum and print these out from text (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, xcode, python-3.6

**From the original text as attached below, I've tried to write a program to count the number of days that appears in this file. For instance, it would count the number of times that Sat(Saturdays), Fri(Fridays) and Thu(Thursdays) appears. I've managed to do it, but I would like to know if this is a more systematic way to do this.**

**Below is the content in the text file.**

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
Return-Path: <postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>
Received: from murder (mail.umich.edu [141.211.14.90])
      by frankenstein.mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.3.8) with LMTPA;
     Sat, 05 Jan 2008 09:14:16 -0500
X-Sieve: CMU Sieve 2.3
Received: from murder ([unix socket])
     by mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.2.12) with LMTPA;
     Sat, 05 Jan 2008 09:14:16 -0500
Received: from holes.mr.itd.umich.edu (holes.mr.itd.umich.edu 
[141.211.14.79])
     by flawless.mail.umich.edu () with ESMTP id m05EEFR1013674;
     Sat, 5 Jan 2008 09:14:15 -0500
 Received: FROM paploo.uhi.ac.uk (app1.prod.collab.uhi.ac.uk 
[194.35.219.184])
     BY holes.mr.itd.umich.edu ID 477F90B0.2DB2F.12494 ;
     5 Jan 2008 09:14:10 -0500
Received: from paploo.uhi.ac.uk (localhost [127.0.0.1])
     by paploo.uhi.ac.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id 5F919BC2F2;
     Sat,  5 Jan 2008 14:10:05 +0000 (GMT)
```

"From" with day in the lines

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
From louis@media.berkeley.edu Fri Jan  4 18:10:48 2008
From zqian@umich.edu Fri Jan  4 16:10:39 2008
From rjlowe@iupui.edu Fri Jan  4 15:46:24 2008
From zqian@umich.edu Fri Jan  4 15:03:18 2008
From rjlowe@iupui.edu Fri Jan  4 14:50:18 2008
From cwen@iupui.edu Fri Jan  4 11:37:30 2008
From cwen@iupui.edu Fri Jan  4 11:35:08 2008
From gsilver@umich.edu Fri Jan  4 11:12:37 2008
From gsilver@umich.edu Fri Jan  4 11:11:52 2008
From zqian@umich.edu Fri Jan  4 11:11:03 2008
From gsilver@umich.edu Fri Jan  4 11:10:22 2008
From wagnermr@iupui.edu Fri Jan  4 10:38:42 2008
From zqian@umich.edu Fri Jan  4 10:17:43 2008
From antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk Fri Jan  4 10:04:14 2008
From gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com Fri Jan  4 09:05:31 2008
From david.horwitz@uct.ac.za Fri Jan  4 07:02:32 2008
From david.horwitz@uct.ac.za Fri Jan  4 06:08:27 2008
From david.horwitz@uct.ac.za Fri Jan  4 04:49:08 2008
From david.horwitz@uct.ac.za Fri Jan  4 04:33:44 2008
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Fri Jan  4 04:07:34 2008
From louis@media.berkeley.edu Thu Jan  3 19:51:21 2008
From louis@media.berkeley.edu Thu Jan  3 17:18:23 2008
From ray@media.berkeley.edu Thu Jan  3 17:07:00 2008
From cwen@iupui.edu Thu Jan  3 16:34:40 2008
From cwen@iupui.edu Thu Jan  3 16:29:07 2008
From cwen@iupui.edu Thu Jan  3 16:23:48 2008
```

My Code

```
fname = input('Enter the file name: ')
word1 = []
try:
    fhand = open('D:/Python/%s' %(fname))
except:
    print('File cannot be opened:' , fname)
    exit()
counts = dict()
for line in fhand:
    words = line.rstrip()
    print(words)
    if(not words.startswith('From:') == True): #Exclude "From:" lines since they don't contain days
        if(words.startswith('From') == True):  #Print lines that contain "From" since they contain days
               s = words
               a = s.split()
               for b in a:
                  counts[b] = counts.get(b,0) + 1
for key in counts:
    if(key == ('Sat') or key== ('Fri') or key == ('Thu')):
         print(key, counts[key])
```

**Result:**
    Sat 1
    Fri 20
    Thu 6

Comment: I don't understand. There are many 'Sat' in your file but your output for 'Sat' is 1.

Comment: I'm edited the post, adding all the lines that start with From and contain day

Answer (score 0):

Your example input only includes `Sat` ?

```
from collections import Counter
import re

myStr = """From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan......."""

Counter(re.findall(r'(Sat|Fri|Thu)\b', myStr))
# Counter({'Sat': 5})
```

Comment: It's just part of the content in the text since its too chunky to put the whole thing here

Comment: I'm edited the post, adding all the lines that start with From and contain day in it